# angular file upload in mobile browser memory leak

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, memory-leaks, ng-file-upload

I am working with the latest version of [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and seeing huge memory consumption(>1gb) when uploading over 50 images. I am hoping to handle upwards of 500 images specifically from an iphone. It seems the leaks are caused by the `resize` and `applyExifRotation` promises.I have been using the task manager in Chrome to test memory usage. Any suggestions on refactoring would be appreciated.

I have a button with the following attributes.

```
<button ng-hide="uploading" accept="image/*" class="button" ngf-select ngf-change="doit($files)" ngf-multiple="true">Select Files</button>
```

with a controller like:

```
var CHUNKSIZE = 5;
    $scope.doit = function(files) {
        $scope.remaining = files.length;
        $scope.fileChunks = _.chunk(files, CHUNKSIZE);
        $scope.uploadChunk(0);
    }

    $scope.uploadChunk = function(i) {
        var uploaded = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.fileChunks[i], function(f) {
            Upload.resize(f, 1000).then(function(f) {
                return f;
            }).then(function(f) {
                Upload.applyExifRotation(f).then(function(f) {
                    uploaded++;
                    $scope.uploadFile(f);
                    if (uploaded == CHUNKSIZE) {
                        $scope.uploadChunk(i + 1);
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    }
```

You can see a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/nwy08oak/15/